# How can I escape character '&' in Path in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I escape character '&' in Path in XAML?

I need to escape (using XML entities) certain characters that are special to the XML language definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try '&amp'.  [XAML escape character entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms748250.aspx). Or '&#x26'.  MSDN [escape characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). [Ascii Table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (from asciitable.com)

Answer (score 0):

ouflak's answer didn't work for me now. According to msdn [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-special-characters-in-xaml?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) you need to use `&amp;`